# Git: Remove directory from branch without affecting other branch

Tags: git

I would like to:

1. Checkout a new branch B2
2. Delete directories
3. Switch back to master and see the directories I deleted.

Instead, what I'm experiencing is that the directories I delete with B2 checked out are also appear removed when I checkout master.

```
git checkout master
ls
. .. dir1/ dir2/
git checkout -b B2
rm -rf dir2/
ls
. .. dir1/
git checkout master
ls 
. .. dir1/
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+directory+switch+branch

Answer (score 2):

In the branch you want the directories deleted in, you need to `add` and `commit` those changes before moving back to `master`.